# How can i change Navigation Title color, Character spacing & Font style from Storyboard for iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am able to change character spacing, title color & font style programmatically. Here is the sample code

```
 let titleLabel = UILabel()
let colour = UIColor.redColor()
let attributes: [NSString : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour, NSKernAttributeName : 5.0]
titleLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "My String", attributes: attributes)
titleLabel.sizeToFit()
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

but i want to change these three from storyboard. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it's not possible using Storyboard